# How to set dashed grid lines on 3D chart?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, qt5, data-visualization

[image]

Dashed line grid can be achieved on 2D chart by doing:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtCharts>

using namespace QtCharts;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    auto chart = new QChart;
    chart->addSeries(new QLineSeries);
    chart->createDefaultAxes();
    chart->axes(Qt::Horizontal)[0]->setGridLinePen(Qt::DashLine);
    chart->legend()->hide();

    QChartView view(chart);
    view.show();
    view.resize(400,300);

    return a.exec();
}
```

And 3D chart can be achieved by doing:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <Q3DBars>

using namespace QtDataVisualization;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {

    auto chart = new Q3DBars;
    setCentralWidget(QWidget::createWindowContainer(chart));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}
```

How to set dashed grid lines on 3D chart?

Comment: Seeing your multiple questions here about fitting Qt's chart to your needs, my advice is to simply roll your own rendering code. It's much simpler than you think.

Comment: Well, then I should ask where should start doing that?